# mapbox GL JS - pass source data to custom layer

Tags: mapbox-gl-js, maplibre-gl

I've added some quads with custom shaders to map (Examples are [here](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/custom-style-layer/) and [here](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/blob/main/src/style/style_layer/custom_style_layer.js)).  I need to pass data from my source to shader. [Tutorials](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/animate-point-along-line/) says that I can just pass `'source': 'point',` to layer class constructor. Is it possible to pass source data to [custom layer](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/blob/main/src/style/style_layer/custom_style_layer.js)?

Here is source example:

```
map.addSource('point', {
    'type': 'geojson',
    'data': {
        'type': 'FeatureCollection',
        'features': [
            {
                'type': 'Feature',
                'geometry': {
                    'type': 'Point',
                    'coordinates': [0, 0]
                            }
            }
                    ]
              }
    });
```